# how to assign start index value for string[]

Tags: .net, vb.net

`Str_Array as String()`  \ in 10 strings

i want starting from 3 index value to end value

`Array_Str as String()`

`Array_Str= ?`   \ how to specify starting index value?

Comment: UiPath has nothing to do with how .NET or VB.NET work. The question doesn't make sense either - if you just want to retrieve some items from the array, why don't you do just that? Are you looking for a VB.NET intro perhaps? Or the [docs for arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) ?

Comment: Is the real question "How can I extract a range of items from an array without looping" ? You can use [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Are you looking for `Array_Str = Str_Array.Skip(3).ToArray()`? Also, remember that array indexes start at 0, not 1, and it is a good idea to give variables meaningful names.

Comment: If your desire is to dimension a `String()` starting with index 3, as a practical matter, this can't be done due to some design details in .NET.  Single-rank arrays are forced to be "vectors" under-the-hood which have a fixed lower bound of 0.  It's possible to create a single-rank `System.Array` with a different lower bound, but this will not be compatible with a declared single-rank array.  There is, unfortunately, no direct language support for non-zero lower bounds even for `System.Array`s, you have to make it happen by calling a ctor or static factory method directly.

Comment: (Insert rant about poor design decision on fixed and prefer-0 lower bounds in .NET which can never be fixed.)